# Adding more than one gradle dependency

Tags: codenameone

I've added a dependency to a via the build hints

```
android.gradleDep=implementation("androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0")
```

I'd like to add another

```
android.gradleDep=implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6")
```

However when I add this second one, the first is replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place them one after the other with a semicolon in between. That's valid Gradle syntax. Specifically

```
android.gradleDep=implementation("androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"); implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6")
```